# failedget container runtime's cgroup:failedget containername fordocker process:mountpoint forcpu notfound.Runtime systemcontainer metric maybe missing

Tags: linux

i am facing the error in my oracle linux server 9.1. I have installed 20.10.17 docker and 2.4.9 rancher version

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to install 2.7.1 rancher on 9.1 oracle linux. I have installed all the images through command then i checked logs "docker logs container ID" then i am facing that issue " failed to get container runtime's cgroup : failed to get container name for docker process : mountpoint for cpu not found. Runtime system container metric maybe missing "